# Adding two custom commands at once in SublimeGit?

Tags: git, heroku, github, sublimetext

I want to configure a custom SublimeGit command which automatically pushes to Heroku and GitHub.

Git.sublime-commands:

```
[
{
    "caption": "Git: Push to Heroku and GH",
    "command": "git_custom",
    "args": {
        "cmd": "push origin master && push heroku master",
        "output": "panel",
        "async": false
    }
}
]
```

However, when I try to call the command, Sublime tells me that the refspec '&&' has not been found. Is there another solution as on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible. But feel free to go to https://github.com/SublimeGit/SublimeGit/issues and submit a feature request.

(I'm the creator of SublimeGit btw)